# Google maps loads partly hidden infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

So i have the following code to display an info window when the map loads.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-1.09694,37.01535409999997); //Google map Coordinates
   var map;
    map_initialize(); //load map
    function map_initialize()   
    {
        //Google map option
        var googleMapOptions =
        {
            center: mapCenter, // map center
            zoom: 17, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
            panControl: true, //enable pan Control
            zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
            zoomControlOptions: {style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
        },
            mapTypeControlOptions:
            {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
            },
            scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),googleMapOptions);

        var image = '/resource-image-files/brand_full.png';
        var infodata = '<section id="content" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;"><h1 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;"><img style="position:relative;left:0%;" width="15%" height="15%" src="/resource-image-files/brand_full.png" alt="Fair Acres House, Karen"/> Fair Acres House, Karen</h1><article><p>Welcome to Fair Acres House, Karen. Get the best accommodation at our exquisite suites.</p><p>We are located in a Karen, A short drive from Nairobi and at the foot of the Ngong Hills.</p><p>For More information, get <a href="http://fairacres-nairobi.co.ke">Fair Acres site</a> For More Information.</p></article></section>';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: infodata});
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: mapCenter,
            map:map,
            title: "FairAcres House, Karen"
            //icon: image
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    //infowindow.open(map,marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(window, 'load', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});
    }
});
```

I want the div to display the div when the page loads. Well it works perfect. except for one small issue. 
The top of the infowindow is partly hidden by the top border of the #map div. Therefore, for the user to view the top of the text with the 'close' button, the must scroll down.
Obviously this is boring so I want to get rid of it.
Question is,
How do i make sure the infowindow is in full view when it loads.
Below is a sucky image of how it shows.
[image: SUCKY INFOWINDOW]

Comment: Read more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions

Comment: ??? By default, the info window will pan the map so that it is fully visible when it opens.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems(I guess the question is related to [this page](http://fairacres-nairobi.co.ke/location/)) this issue is caused by the marker.

At least for me at first the infowindow loads at the correct position and panned so that it is fully visible. Then the marker loads(the browser needs a moment to load the image). When the marker is visible the infowindow jumps upwards, partially outside of the viewport.

**The reason:** when you open a infowindow bound to a marker the API needs to know the size of the marker(you may have noticed that the tip of the infowindow is placed on top of the marker, and not at the marker-position....it would cover the marker when it's placed on the marker-position).

**So the problem is:** when the infowindow opens the size of the marker is still unknown for the API.

**Possible solution:** open the infowindow at the marker-position and use the pixelOffset-option based on the size(you may know the size beforehand) of the marker(the default-marker has a size of 22x40)to place the infowindow on top of the marker:

```
infowindow.setOptions({position:marker.getPosition(),
                       pixelOffset:new google.maps.Size(0,-40),
                       map:map});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This css

```
.centerMarker{
  position:absolute;      
  background:url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png) no-repeat; /*URL of Marker*/
  top:50%;left:50%;/*use to center marker*/    
  z-index:1;
  /*Use the offset*/
  margin-left:-10px;
  margin-top:-34px;
  /*size of the image*/
  height:34px;
  width:20px;    
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/jcHqt/14/)